# Can't retrieve values from foreach loop under CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-2, variable-assignment

I can't retrieve values from $info (as stated below) in CodeIgniter View.

Here is the scenario:
I explained everything the code.

```
function info() {
{...} //I retrieve results from database after sending $uid to model.
    $dbresults = $this->my_model->get_info($uid); //Assume that this model returns some value.


    foreach($dbresults as $row) {
        $info = $row->address; //This is what I need to produce the results
        $results = $this->my_model->show_info($info);

    return $results; //This is my final result which can't be achieved without using $row->address. so first I have to call this in my controller.

    }

    // Now I want to pass it to a view

    $data['info'] = $results;
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);

    //In my_view, $info contains many values inherited from $results which I need to call one by one by using foreach. But I can't use $info with foreach because it is an Invalid Parameter as it says in an error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `$result` inside `foreach` is not reasonable. Because in each loop $result will take a new value. So, preferably use it as an `array` and then pass it to your view. Besides, you should not use `return` inside `foreach`.

```
function info() {
{...} //I retrieve results from database after sending $uid to model.
    $dbresults = $this->my_model->get_info($uid); //Assume that this model returns some value

$result = array();
    foreach($dbresults as $row) {
        $info = $row->address; //This is what I need to produce the results
        $result[] = $this->my_model->show_info($info);

    }

    // Now I want to pass it to a view

    $data['info'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

to check what $result array has do `var_export($result);` or `var_dump($result);` after the end of `foreach`. and make sure that this is what you want to send to your view.

Now, in your view you can do:

```
<?php foreach ($info as $something):?>

//process

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove **return** statement from

```
foreach($dbresults as $row) {
    $info = $row->address; //This is what I need to produce the results
    $results[] = $this->my_model->show_info($info);
    //  return $results; remove this line from here;
}

$data['info'] = $results; // now in view access by $info in foreach
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

now $info can be access in view.

hope this will help you!